# How do I navigate a directory in the GHCi shell?

Tags: haskell

The tutorial I'm reading says after we've defined the function, we need to go to where it is saved and load it. The GHCi shell that I'm using seems to only interpret Haskell, meaning I can't move anywhere. How can this be done other than moving the file to the directory where the shell is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `:cd` command:

```
$ ghci
ghci> :cd directory/to/move/to
```

Comment: Thanks. Does the directory need to be in quotes?

Comment: @user2030677 It doesn't need to be, but I only tested with a directory without spaces in it, so you might need them in that case.

Comment: How do I know what directory I'm in and what's in it?

Comment: Use `:?` to find every possible command. `:! dir` will use the `dir` shell command, showing the current directory.